# Sphinx exclude torch.tensor as T

Tags: python, pytorch, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm aware of how to exclude files from Sphinx.

However, a handful of my code uses the standard pattern of:

```py
import torch.tensor as T
```

`T` then ends up getting the torch tensor documentation in my modules. How can I avoid this?

I am using these sphinx extensions:

```
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
    "sphinx_rtd_theme",
]
```

Here are example warnings from `make html`:

```
/Users/joseph/dev/torchsynth/torchsynth/parameter.py:docstring of torchsynth.parameter.T:1: WARNING: Inline emphasis start-string without end-string.
/Users/joseph/dev/torchsynth/torchsynth/util.py:docstring of torchsynth.util.T:1: WARNING: Inline emphasis start-string without end-string.
```

For example, in `torchsynth/parameter.py` the imports are

```
from typing import Optional

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import tensor as T
```

This is the [sphinx branch](https://github.com/turian/torchsynth/tree/sphinx) in github. We just started writing our sphinx docs, so please be gentle.

Our `rst` files right now are just skeletons. For example, `module.rst` is:

```
torchsynth
==========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   torchsynth
```

You can see other rsts [here](https://github.com/turian/torchsynth/tree/sphinx/docs/source) in the branch.

Attached is a screenshot of my py-modindex.py:

[image]

You can see the floating 't' at the top left. The plus/minus button is overly scaled, I think I need to adjust the theme, but that's not my issue.

Comment: Which Sphinx extension are you using that yield this result? autogen, autodoc, autosummary, something else? Your question lacks sufficient information to replicate your issue.

Comment: I have edited my comment with the sphinx extensions I am using

Comment: autodoc is the sphinx extension I'm using but I'm open to alternatives

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"T then ends up getting the torch tensor documentation in my modules"*. Can you post an MRE? An example `.rst` and `.py` preferably showing the output HTML?

Comment: @bad_coder I have updated the question with more information and a link to our documentation branch.

Comment: Putting docstrings at the start of the file might be the reason you get the warnings. Try using Python comment instead. After that, I am with @bad_coder in that I do not understand your statement, even after you have updated your question. It makes no sense.

Comment: @StevePiercy I have removed the docstrings at the top and rebuilt, but I still have the issue. I will attach a screenshot.